# Нужна ли запятая? (5)

Tags: пунктуация, или

*Не пишите или пишите правильно.* Нужна ли запятая перед *или?*

Answer (score 1):

***Не пишите или пишите правильно.***

Запятая не ставится.

Это сложносочиненное предложение, состоит из двух односоставных определенно-личных предложений, сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме повелительного наклонения. Такие предложения можно назвать побудительными и применить правило Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав  входят:

2) **побудительные предложения:** Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! (Фурм.) — объединяет побудительная интонация; Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло! — объединяет побудительная частица; Да будет свято имя героя и память о нём сохранится в веках! — объединяет побудительная частица;

Хотя в этом правиле упоминается побудительная (восклицательная, вероятно) интонация или побудительные частицы, но и при их отсутствии **в определенно-личных предложениях можно найти общий элемент:** первое лицо (говорящий) или второе лицо (адресат).

Поэтому в определенно-личных предложениях при наличии одиночного союза ИЛИ запятая не ставится, например: (1) Приеду вечером или останусь здесь до утра.(2) Перепишите текст и вставьте пропущенные буквы.

Такие предложения фактически приравниваются **к однородным членам,** поэтому запятая в них при наличии одиночных союзов И, ИЛИ не ставится.

Comment: Здесь логически явно делается интонационная пауза и лучше поставить запятую. Смысл такой: *В таком варианте вообще лучше не пишите... Или пишите всё-таки правильно*.

Comment: oleedd, откуда вы-то знаете смысл, который имел в виду автор?

Comment: *Хотя в этом правиле упоминается побудительная* - в примере побудительная интонация очевидно имеет место. Это же повелительное наклонение,даже без восклицательного знака.

Comment: @behemothus "откуда вы-то знаете смысл, который имел в виду автор" --- дело в том, что иного смысла и быть не может.

Comment: @oleedd правда? А откуда знаете, что не может?

Comment: @oleedd Вы перебирали варианты? Какие же?

Comment: Вот сколько ни перебираю "варианты" слово "вариант"  ну никак не лезет.

Comment: Только один возможен (в рациональном контексте).